# xpath doesnt correctly select HTML in Scrapy's parse

Tags: xpath, scrapy, screen-scraping, scrapy-splash

I am trying to parse the product names on this [Target search page](https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=google%20home%20%2B) with Scrapy and Splash. I use Splash to send a request  `yield SplashRequest(url=i, callback=self.parse, headers = {"User-Agent": ua.chrome})` and then use the parse function to extract the `product_name`:

```html
def parse(self, response):

    print("INSIDE PARSE TARGET")
    for product in response.xpath('//div[@data-test="productGridContainer"]/div[2]/ul/li//div[@data-test="product-card"]'):

        print("in PRODUCT")

        print(product)
        product_name = product.xpath('.//div[@data-test="productCardBody"]/div[@data-test="product-details"]/div[contains(@class,"ProductTitle")]/a[1]/@aria-label').extract_first()
        print("Product name: " + str(product_name))
        print("ratio: " + str(fuzz.partial_ratio(target_name.lower(), product_name.lower())))

        if fuzz.partial_ratio(target_name.lower(), product_name.lower()) > self.max_score:
            self.max_score = fuzz.partial_ratio(target_name.lower(), product_name.lower())
            self.product_page = product.xpath('.//div[@data-test="productCardBody"]/div[@data-test="product-details"]/div[contains(@class,"ProductTitle")]/a[1]/@href').extract_first()
            print("product_page: " + self.product_page)

        print("---------------------------------------")

    print("***********************************")
    print("max_score is: " + str(self.max_score))
    self.product_page = response.urljoin(self.product_page)
    print("FOUND PRODUCT AT PAGE: " + self.product_page)
    yield SplashRequest(url=self.product_page, callback=self.parseProduct, headers = {"User-Agent": ua.chrome})
```

However, this is all I get. It never goes inside the for loop, which I dont understand.

```html
2018-08-01 14:08:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-08-01 14:08:04 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-08-01 14:08:04 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6044
2018-08-01 14:08:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=google+home+%2B via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
INSIDE PARSE TARGET
***********************************
max_score is: 0
FOUND PRODUCT AT PAGE: https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=google+home+%2B
2018-08-01 14:08:07 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=google+home+%2B> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2018-08-01 14:08:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no loop in your crawler. As this log line shows:

> DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=google+home+%2B> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)

You are trying to crawl again a page you just crawled, and scrapy's dupe filter is filtering this request out.

Seems like your `self.product_page` returns the same url you, not a new one. I've refactored your code a bit to try to understand your issue:

```
def parse(self, response):
    products = response.xpath('//div[@data-test="productGridContainer"]/div[2]/ul/li//div[@data-test="product-card"]')
    max_score = 0
    target_name = '???'
    product_page = None
    for product in products:
        name = product.xpath('.//div[@data-test="productCardBody"]/div[@data-test="product-details"]/div[contains(@class,"ProductTitle")]/a[1]/@aria-label').extract_first()
        url = product.xpath('.//div[@data-test="productCardBody"]/div[@data-test="product-details"]/div[contains(@class,"ProductTitle")]/a[1]/@href').extract_first()
        if response.urljoin(url) == response.url:
            continue # avoid crawling current page
        ratio = fuzz.partial_ratio(target_name.lower(), name.lower()))
        if ratio > self.max_score:
            max_score = ratio
            product_page = url

    if product_page:
        print(f'max_score: {max_score}')
        print(f'product: {product_page}')
        yield SplashRequest(response.urljoin(product_page), 
                            callback=self.parse_product, 
                            headers = {"User-Agent": ua.chrome})
```

Comment: but your code is no different from mine. I tried your code, and it still doesnt enter the for loop `for product in products:`. My xpath is correct, so I dont know why this isnt working